# WebStorm critical error on Windows 10 operating system

Tags: windows, webstorm, intellij-14

I'm facing a problem on running **WebStorm** from my laptop which is running on Windows 10 pro operating system. I search on Google but I couldn't get a solution for this error..

> Internal error. Please report to http://jb.gg/ide/critical-startup-errors

`java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: C:\Users\Dell\.WebStorm2018.1\config\port.lock
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.translateToIOException(WindowsException.java:83)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:97)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsException.rethrowAsIOException(WindowsException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(WindowsFileSystemProvider.java:115)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.a(SocketLock.java:176)
    at com.intellij.idea.SocketLock.lock(SocketLock.java:125)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.a(StartupUtil.java:309)
    at com.intellij.idea.StartupUtil.prepareAndStart(StartupUtil.java:116)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.a(MainImpl.java)
    at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl.start(MainImpl.java:41)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager.a(PluginManager.java:77)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: 1) Check file permissions fro the whole `C:\Users\Dell\.WebStorm2018.1\` folder (all child elements) 2) Is that location is actually on local disk .. or it's some Network profile (when user home is located on a server)? 2) Maybe even some Antivirus or cloud disk access issue (if that folder for some strange reason is synced via OneDrive or alike) 4) With such errors it's better to contact JetBrains Support

Comment: Not really! I just buy a new laptop and two days ago i running successfully...

Comment: Well -- try this then: ensure that IDE is closed completely; go to and delete that port.lock file; double check folder permissions; try launching again... Other than that: backup whole `C:\Users\Dell\.WebStorm2018.1\config` folder into ZIP/RAR/7Z archive (not just copy-paste or rename locally) and delete whole `C:\Users\Dell\.WebStorm2018.1` folder; then restore from archive backup (it should not remember individual file permissions). No other solid ideas right now.

Comment: After deleting `port.lock` file from **config** and **system** folder ,now its work for me. Thank you @LazyOne

Answer (score 1):

You have to delete the `port.lock` file.

Comment: Yeah ! I got answer from comments. Thank you